# Asp.Net mvc, How to make async and await method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I use this two actions to send email to admins about inventory status when it's time to make an order...
But When I call SendEmailToAdminUser .. it takes time and side by side I cant work with other functions... waiting litle long..
I want to change those functions to async and await Task ... but I don't how to do. I tried to change from JsonResult to ActionResult ...

```
public JsonResult SendEmailToAdminUser()
{
    bool result = false;

    var emails = UserEmails();

    if (emails != null)
    {
        foreach (var email in emails)
        {
            var departmentId = context.Users.Where(e => e.Email == email)
                .Select(s => s.DepartmentId).FirstOrDefault();

            string departmentname = context.Departments.Where(u => u.deptId == departmentId)
                .Select(n => n.DepartmentName).Single();

            int[] ProductId = context.Inventory.Where(s => s.prId == departmentId)
                .Where(s => s.Status == 10).Select(s => s.PrId).ToArray();

            foreach (var product in ProductId)
            {
                string productname = context.Products.Where(n => n.prId == product)
                    .Select(n => n.ProductName).Single();

                result = SendEmail(email, productname, "<p> Hi there, <br />It is time to order " 
                    + productname + " to department: " + departmentname + "</p> <br /> /Regards");
            }
        }
    }

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

And my SendEmail function is:

```
public bool SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string emailBody)
{
    try
    {
        string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString();
        string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"].ToString();

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 100000;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody);
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        client.Send(mailMessage);

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Making it `async` does not make any difference to the time taken (it just means that you release the thread so it can be used by other requests)

Comment: And your `return Json(result, ...)` does not make much sense. If the first 20 fail, but the last one succeeds, your method returns `true`

Comment: you might consider merging all the product names to a single email and send to user. At least that will change it from O(M*N) to O(M) calls

Comment: @StephenMuecke so you mean it is not bad as it is..? I have two buttons.. + and - Increase and Decrease products... and when I click Decrease button and when status of Product decrease to 10 and then it sends email ... and I have to wait litle to deacrease more, my decrease button freezing while sending email. But its just seconds.. so I can live with that ,,;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by commenters you won’t get any benefits from async/await as you’ll just be releasing the underlying thread for other requests. Actual execution time will likely be *longer* than what you currently have.

It sounds like what you actually want is concurrency which can be easily achieved using a `Parallel.ForEach`. However, before complicating your code I’d suggest a couple of changes first.

- Re-use your instance of `SmtpClient`. There is overhead in instantiating this for every call because it’ll need to connect to the backend SMTP service every time.
- As Shyju points out, optimise your algorithm. Right now you’re sending multiple emails to the *same* email address in a loop. You can merge these together to minimise the amount of calls to `SendMail`.
- Minimise the number of database calls you’re making by making calls for multiple things at once.

From your code above:

```
public JsonResult SendEmailToAdminUser()
{
    bool result = false;

    var emails = UserEmails();

    if (emails != null)
    {
        // fetching data in batches
        var departmentIdsByEmail = context.Users
            .Where(x => emails.Contains(x.Email))
            .Select(x => new { x.Email, x.DepartmentId })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Email, x => x.DepartmentId);

        var departmentIds = departmentIdsByEmail.Values;

        var departmentNamesById = context.Departments
            .Where(x => departmentIds.Contains(x.deptId))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.deptId, x => x.DepartmentName);

        var productNamesByDepartmentId = context.Inventory
            .Where(x => departmentIds.Contains(x.deptId))
            .Where(x => x.Status == 10)
            .GroupBy(x => x.deptId)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.Product.Name).ToArray());

        foreach (var emailWithDepartmentId in departmentIdsByEmail)
        {
            // send **one** email per address rather than many
            var email = emailWithDepartmentId.Key
            var departmentId = emailWithDepartmentId.Value;
            var departmentName = departmentNamesById[departmentId];
            var productNames = productNamesByDepartmentId[departmentId];

            result = SendEmail(
                email, 
                "<p> Hi there, <br />It is time to order "                      + string.Join(", ", productNames) + " to department: " + departmentName + "</p> <br /> /Regards");

        }
    }

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}

private static readonly SmtpClient _smtpClient = CreateSmtpClient();

private static SmtpClient CreateSmtpClient()
{
     string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString();
     string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"].ToString();

     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
     client.EnableSsl = true;
     client.Timeout = 100000;
     client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
     client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);

     return client;
}

public bool SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string emailBody)
{
    string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString();
    try
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody);
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        _smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That's fairly thrown together but should hopefully give you a start. In essence you just need to try to minimise the amount of I/O you're doing and you should see substantial performance improvements!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I get two errors with your code. The first one is in return error in CreateSmtpClient() The error message is "An object of a type convertible to 'SmtpClient' is required" This happen in return; The other one is Inside SendEmail method  MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody); The error message is "The name 'senderEmail' does not exist in the current context" Maybe you have to difine maybe This name is not defined in SendEmail method... Thank you again

Comment: I made adjustments, but I haven’t compiled or tested the code written here. It’s more a way of understanding how to modify and optimise your existing code!

Comment: thank you, now no error for that matter, There is now only one error. productNamesByDepartmentId inside SendEmailToAdminUser()  threwing NullReferenceException in ToDirection ...
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.Product.Name).ToArray());
Erro message = 'x.Product.Name' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: You’ll need to modify it to work with your database context. I don’t know how that’s configured. Presumably you have a relationship between the product and the inventory, so make modifications to the code to fix it!